# MVC4 External Login: Google provider button disappeared

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, oauth

The Problem: I used to be able to login to my MVC4 website using Google external login but suddenly **the "Google" button doesn't appear**. I get no such behavior when I try a new clean MVC4 project.

Debugging shows that the `IsAuthenticatedWithOAuth` property of the `OAuthWebSecurity` object throws a "Missing Method Exception" when `ExternalLoginsList` action in the AccountController tries to return the _ExternalLoginsListPartial view. Then, when rendering the _loginPartial view, the `Request.IsAuthenticated` is false. Also, the generated HTML includes the code for the button (so it means it's an authentication issue?)

The website is supposed to run on windows Azure but the problem occurs both in the cloud and when running locally. Actually the first time the button disappeared was after publishing a new version of the website to Azure.

3 hours of going round and round this and I'm not any closer to a solution.
Badly need help here. Thanks